# Argumento invalido para chmod()?

Tags: php, arquivo, post, file-upload

Estou tentando receber as dimensões de cada foto enviada, porém quando executo o arquivo acontece isso:

Erro:

```
  Warning: chmod(): Invalid argument in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-
  Devserver-17\eds-www\PPI\adm\cadastrar_jogo.php on line 15

  Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\Program Files   
  (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\PPI\adm\cadastrar_jogo.php on line 16
```

Eis a parte do código que está dando o erro:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['img']); $i++){
    if (isset($_FILES['img']['name'][$i])){
    if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'][$i])){
     chmod($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i], 0777);
      list ($larg, $alt) = getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i]);
          $verifica_quant_img++;
```

Como posso resolver o problema, e qual é exatamente o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Mas não tem muito sentido usar `chmod` em um arquivo que esta na pasta `./tmp` do sistema operacional, você deve usar primeiro o `move_upload` e depois aplicar `chmod` no novo destino.

Também seria interessante checar se houve erro com o `$_FILES['img']['error']`, veja um exemplo de uso:

```
if (empty($_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {
    echo 'Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo';//Aqui você pode trocar por um alert ou customizar como desejar, é um aviso que o usuário provavelmente não selecionou nada
} else {
    $arquivos = $_FILES['img'];
    $total = count($arquivos['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $nome = $arquivos['name'][$i];

        if ($arquivos['error'][$i] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            echo 'Erro ao fazer upload de ', htmlspecialchars($nome), '<br>';
            continue;
        }

        $destino = 'pasta/foo/bar/' . $nome;

        if (move_uploaded_file($arquivos['tmp_name'][$i], $destino)) {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' foi carregado<br>';
            chmod($destino, 0777);
        } else {
            echo 'O arquivo ', htmlspecialchars($nome),' não foi carregado<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Todavia, acho que usar `0777` seja exagero para imagens, talvez `644` esteja mais que suficiente.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, o problema é que eu estou enviando arquivos no input, porém quando envio uma imagem do tipo PNG aparace o erro da função getimagesize(). Assim utilizei o chmod() por achar que era algo relacionado as permissões, já que os arquivos PNG geralmente são maiores...

Comment: @shelldude pode ser falha no upload, faça a checagem **primero** (antes de tudo) como no exemplo `if ($arquivos['error'][$i] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)`